# Git show command puts the "newline" and "=" symbol where I don't need them

Tags: git

**Input -** 2 GIT TAGS

I need to get an output from git log with information about **all the commits between these GIT TAGS** **in this format**:

[image: The format that I need]

I am trying to make it in this format. I use the command

```
git show -s --format=%B"   "%an"   "%ad"   "%H cd427aaccb1f90637ae005..16360b36df8a22525f
```

but in the output I get this:

[image: output]

So you can see that there is a newline and symbol "=" that i don't need. Could you tell me, what am I doing wrong and how to get, what I want?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: But `%B` is body...

Comment: the body of commit message? How can I show it without a new line?

Comment: but the body also ctains diffs/conflicts/... you probably want the *subject* `%s`.

Comment: you probably want `%s` instead of `%B`, no?

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, it works! I also figured out, what is a problem with "=" symbol. This symbol was inside of username, so it is in a log with "=". Could you tell me one another thing? I also need to show a username, but it should be taken from the email config information. For example, if the email is ilyasr@gmail.com, it should be ilyasr. How can i get it and show in the log by using a command from above?